# Is it possible to fetch Google Analytics events?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is it possible to get the events directly from Google Analytics via an API? I'm aware of the streaming export to BigQuery, but I'd like to do it without any additional services, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is.  To extract data from a Universal analytics account you would use the [Google analytics reporting api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/)

If its a GA4 account you can use the [Google analytics data api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1)

There are official client libraries for most languages already in place to make it easer for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! These APIs can only return reports, not events themselves though.

Comment: well the reports contain the events i guess depends on how you look at it.   You cant get the direct hits back if thats what your looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The non-aggregated, log/event level export (streamed or batched) is only available via BigQuery. You have options to export data from BigQuery. There is no way to plug into the streaming channel to BigQuery and redirect those hits either.

A cumbersome alternative would be to stream events to the platform of your choosing on the collection side. However, you would miss out on quite a few processed and calculated fields that GA provides for you.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, Luka! When you say "stream events to the platform of your choosing on the collection side" what do you mean by "on the collection side"?